# Is a cubic Lagrange interpolation tensor product the same as bicubic interpolation?

Tags: interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I just implemented some interpolated texture sampling by sampling the 4x4 nearest pixels then doing Lagrange interpolation across the x axis to get four values to use Lagrange interpolation on across the y axis.

Is this the same as bicubic interpolation?

Webgl implementation here: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MllSzX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it turns out that it is not the same thing.  Bicubic interpolation is $C1$ continuous, while lagrange is not.  It's a completely different thing.

From left to right we have:  nearest neighbor, bilinear, bi-cubiclagrange and bi-cubic.
[image]

More info here:
http://blog.demofox.org/2015/08/15/resizing-images-with-bicubic-interpolation/